# Simulate Ctrl key at keyDown event of textBox in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, microsoft-ui-automation

I m using richTextbox in my application & inside chrome, richtextbox isnt capturing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> key

I found it is a bug, but i dont want to use third party hotfixes for it.

richTextbox can recognize <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> & <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> key
So I've decided to simulate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key at keydown event of richTextbox

But I don't know how to simulate it without `SendKeys` ?
I've gone through UI automation but m not finding the keyboard simulation.

Any help ?

Comment: Are you sure it`s a bug? So the space key press is not recognized at all? Does it hit KeyDown?

Comment: So is KeyDown hit or not? Why emulate "Ctrl" key if you can just insert space on "Space" press?

Comment: When i press Space key, there is no response from keyDown event. For other keys silverlight executes all code inside KeyDown event. Only when i press CTRL+Space or Shift+Space then silverlight executes code inside keyDown event, thats why i want to simulate CTRL key at every keyDown event

Answer (score 0):

It was javascript hotkey overriding Space key in silverlight.
I m using javascript for hotkeys in my application & space is bound to some function. whenever i m pressing space (when silverlight textbox has focus ), javascript is executing that function, so i removed key from javascript.

Now it is working fine in chrome.

Because of this link i thought its a bug

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125924

I apologize for blaming silverlight & visual studio & expression blend, it was javascript.